# What is "cold war"?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, politics

How should I translate "cold war" in Latin?
I can see two ways to approach this, using a classical phrase for a similar hostile political situation, or finding a suitable adjective for "cold" to go together with *bellum*.
There are several adjectives for coldness of some kind, and the most appropriate one I found is *frigidus* (see [L&S, II.C](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=frigidus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) as it means both cold and frightening.
However, the best choice might have nothing to do with temperature.
How would you go about expressing cold war in Latin?

Comment: Not really an answer, but a starker choice would be [*gelidum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgelidus).